# Mono for Android App crashes on start after clears data in app settings

Tags: xamarin.android

I have found that my Mono for Android app crashes on each start after the user goes to Settings->Apps->MyApp and selects "Clear Data". I created a new project with the Mono for Android "Hello World" application, and this app exhibits exactly the same behaviour, which leeds me to the assumption this happens somewhere in the mono stack away from my control. If I check with adb logcat, this are the relevant lines that I can find:

```
I/ActivityManager(  185): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=Test_App.Test_App/test_app.Activity1} from pid 386
D/dalvikvm(18358): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/dalvikvm(18358): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
I/ActivityManager(  185): Start proc Test_App.Test_App for activity Test_App.Test_App/test_app.Activity1: pid=18358 uid=10074 gids={3003}
D/dalvikvm(  119): GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 3% free 12553K/12867K, paused 1ms+2ms
I/ActivityThread(18358): Pub Test_App.Test_App.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
D/dalvikvm(18358): Trying to load lib /data/data/Test_App.Test_App/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x4168ba48
D/dalvikvm(18358): Added shared lib /data/data/Test_App.Test_App/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x4168ba48
D/dalvikvm(  119): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 3% free 12553K/12867K, paused 2ms+2ms
E/mono    (18358): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
E/mono    (18358): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
D/OpenGLRenderer(  386): Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/dalvikvm(  119): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 3% free 12553K/12867K, paused 1ms+1ms
I/mono    (18358): Stacktrace:
I/mono    (18358): 
D/OpenGLRenderer(  386): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/Zygote  (  119): Process 18358 terminated by signal (11)
I/ActivityManager(  185): Process Test_App.Test_App (pid 18358) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  185): Force removing ActivityRecord{41a85018 Test_App.Test_App/test_app.Activity1}: app died, no saved state
```

Does anyone have the same behaviour in his mono apps? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to solve my own question. Under project settings I had to go to "Mono for Android Build" tab, select the Release configuration and make the linker "Link all assemblies" instead of "Link SDK assemblies only". Fixed this by trial and error, but what can you do..

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I've found is to disable the use of the "Shared Runtime" when building the app.

In Visual Studio this is on your Android project settings, Android Options > Packaging tab > Packaging properties > Use Shared Runtime (untick)

It makes the resulting APK a bit bigger, but means users can do "Clear Data" on your app, restart it and it will run without crashing!

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2015 with a Xamarin Forms app on an LG G3 Vigor as a test device. Everything worked fine for many months. I was doing testing for performance documentation so I decided to do Clear Cache on my app in Setting -> General -> Apps on the Vigor. After that was done the Vigor would cause a runtime error when I would deploy my app to the device. The app would work fine on other devices, emulators and iOS simulators.

I tried other suggestions listed on this post. I ended up doing a factory reset on the device. After unlocking developer mode and reconnecting to my computer, it now compiled and ran the app again.

I think a person could try to revoke usb debugging authorizations and re-authorize if they didn't want to do a factory reset, to see if that gets things working again. This may create a different connection path between VS2015 and the device that resets whatever issue was caused by the cache reset. If all else fails, a factory reset did it for me.  Hope it helps in case this happens to someone.